# What can the phrase "form of life" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, difference, understanding

[Source](http://www.cricket.com.au/video/bell-in-the-form-of-my-life/2013-08-11)

In cricket, most commentators use the phrase **form of (his/her) life** for describing players which are **in form** and doing good.

[Source](http://indianexpress.com/article/sports/cricket/india-vs-australia-2017-virat-kohli-is-in-the-form-of-the-decade-says-david-warner-4526385/)

In this source, a player has been called **in the form of the decade.**

I wonder if these phrases mean that they are in the best form that(in which) they have ever been throughout their life. In that case, why don't they say something like this?

> He is in the best form in his life.

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard ***form of the decade*** before (not something said in the US), but I'm guessing the writer is trying to say the player is the best player of the decade. The article goes on to say that he's taking the whole country on a great journey, which would make sense if he's the best player since 2010.